# Login page inside ingress in kubernetes

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

How can I have login page inside my ingress (nginx)? I know I can use basic authentication or OAuth but I want to have a login page just with one user and I don't want it will be like basic authentication. I want it has a specific page.

Comment: What is preventing you having a login place? What problem did you get when you tried?

Comment: @Jonas I want to have better UI instead of basic auth in nginx ingress and if I have login page I can use that for any ingress that I have.

Comment: Yes, do that. What problem did you get when adding a login page?

Comment: I guess you should have a separate authentication service, that handles authentication request and ingress handles and validates authentication session.

Comment: @Jonas My problem is I can't add login page. I only can use basic auth or external basic auth or oauth of nginx ingress controller that they don't solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/xavijs/nginx-basic-auth

---

If I am understanding your question correctly, you’re asking if there’s a way to use http basic auth with a custom HTML form instead of a native browser pop-up dialog.

If that is indeed your question, then yes, you can use XHR (client-side JavaScript) to make a request with the required Authorization: http header.
see:
https://www.peej.co.uk/articles/http-auth-with-html-forms.html

Answer (score 1):

As per this official [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template/#custom-nginx-template) document, you can create a custom nginx page for OAuth or basic authentication nginx ingress controller. For this you have to use the **volume** but at the same time if you are using new template then the **configmap** also needs to be updated.

By using a volume you can add your custom template to nginx deployment like this

```
volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /etc/nginx/template
        name: nginx-template-volume
        readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - name: nginx-template-volume
      configMap:
        name: nginx-template
        items:
        - key: custom-nginx.tmpl
          path: custom-nginx.tmpl
```

For more detailed information on how to use the custom templates refer this document [DOC1](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template/#custom-nginx-template) [DOC2](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/)

Try this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXZr2OC8Unc) for more details (refer to the custom templates section)

Comment: Where should I mount my configMap For having login page with basic authentication credential? Can you give me example?